# Laravel Time Delay For All Timezones While Saving In DB

Tags: database, laravel, timezone

When i am trying to update there is two minutes delay between the actual time and db time . If we print the time it will show the accurate time but while saving to db there will be a 2 minutes delay in time, any idea what is the issue with laravel ?

Comment: Run `SELECT NOW();` in your DB and compare that with your system time to troubleshoot the incorrect time.

Comment: Try updating your server clock: https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp

Comment: Remove the picture from question it adds no value to it, try using words.